# Singly Linked List Reference Manipulation

Tags: java, linked-list

I am Facing problems with Reference Manipulation:
First This is a Code Which takes a value x and traverses the List removing any Link with value Less than or Equal to X but it gives me a irregular output.Help is Appreciated.

```
public void rlx (int x){
        Link p = head;//Initializing a pointer equal to head 
        for (Link c = head.next; c!=null;c=c.next) {//Initializing another Pointer with the Condition to termination
            if((int)head.data<=x){//If the Value of head< = to X
                head=head.next;//Skip the first and assign head to the second
            }else if((int)c.data<=x){
                p.next=c.next;//P.next skip c by pointing to c.next instead of c;
            }
            p=c; reinitialize p;
        }

    }
```

Main Method:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    LinkList l = new LinkList();
    l.insertLast(1);
    l.insertLast(2);
    l.insertLast(3);
    l.insertLast(4);
    l.insertLast(3);
    l.insertLast(2);
    l.insertLast(1);
    l.rlx(3);
    System.out.print(l);
}
```

OutPut: [ 4, 2 ]

Comment: We'd need more information to even begin diagnosing what's going on.  From what I'm looking at, you *could* have an issue with data insertion, too.

Comment: I think the problem is with data deletion because the output Result should be[4] since all other values are equal to or less than x. and i hoped i could do it without using another Linked List. Note this class is made by me and this Method is internally.@Makoto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm has a lot of issues, I'm really not sure where to start. First, you shouldn't be checking the head on each loop iteration, you should only be checking if c.data <= x. Second, you don't remove a node from a single linked list by simply pointing the previous pointer to the node that follows it. You should only be setting p = c if c.data > x not on every iteration. I generally have a rule against doing people's homework, but here

```
public void rlx (int x){
    While(head != null && (int)head.data <= x) {
        head = head.next
    }
    Link p = head;//Initializing a pointer equal to head 
    for (Link c = head.next; c!=null;c=c.next) {//Initializing another Pointer with the Condition to termination
        if((int)c.data<=x){
            p.next=c.next;//P.next skip c by pointing to c.next instead of c;
        }
        Else {
            p=c;
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't bothered to test that because it's basically pseudo code, and I'm assuming your Link type is a pointer object. Basically, you need to do garbage collection explicitly, but more importantly you should be removing the head until you find a value that is larger than x in a while loop, then using a separate for loop to remove values after the head. Otherwise, if the head is smaller than x and c is smaller than x you'll remove the head, which will then become c, but since p is still the old head you'll update your list so that the old head points to the next value which is meaningless because nothing points to p and your current head would be c which isn't greater than x either. Then, p would then become c, which isn't greater than x. p should only ever point to the most recent Link found to be greater than x, and only replaced after you find a Link with value greater than x.